# How to give a class name only for background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

My background image having `width:118px`,On clicking on background image i want to perform some jquery, i cant use `<a>` tag.How to make `cursor:pointer` only on `background` and how to give a class name only for the background? Is it possible? how?

```
<div id="post1_img"></div>

    #post1_img
 {
    width:280px;
height:33px;
background:url(../images/assets/pullTab-readMore-off-.png) no-repeat top center;
clear:both;
  }
```

**EDIT**

[image]

clicking on read more i want to perform some action,Is it possible to do without creating any extra div

```
width of div:280px;

width of image:118px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prash/A8FWa/

Comment: what do you mean clicking on the background?? is the background not an attribute of elements??

Comment: background is  image,its in center of div,on clicking on image i want to perform a jquery

Comment: now I see what you mean.

Comment: please see my jsfiddle to see if this is what you are trying to do.  thx

Comment: Yes my solution will work for this http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/xLx68/2/

Comment: there is no better solution than creating an extra div.

Comment: @ bingjie2680  yea you are right,create an extra div it will make simple,any way i will add a new div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the background image as an background of a div which has the same dimension with the image. then place this div centered inside another div.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="post1_img">
   </div>
</div>

//css
#post1_img{
   width:70px;
   cursor:pointer;
   background:url(pullTab-readMore-off-.png) no-repeat top center;
   /*you need more css here to adjust this div to be center of the outer div*/
}
#outer{
   width:280px;
}

//jquery
$('#post1_img').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: its fine,but i want to create an extra div for this.

Answer (score 2):

Hey now used to  `after` properties in your css

```
<div id="post1_img"></div>
```

**Css**

```
 #post1_img
 {
    width:280px;
height:33px;
background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9932debdde3decc7726b508f43d57438?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat top center;
clear:both;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
  }


 #post1_img:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:50%;
margin-left:-16px;
width:32px;
height:33px;
cursor:pointer;    
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8FWa/2/)

Comment: Then it will show entire div,my div width is 280px;,background is in center width:70px;

Comment: @prash now check to this link http://jsfiddle.net/A8FWa/2/  used to after properties

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a class name to a background image only html elements, but there are some work arounds.  I would suggest you put the image in a div and use cursor:pointer; and position: absolute; and set the z-index: -1; and layer another div over it.

Now that I see your update and screen shot, all you have to do is float an absolute div over the section  of the page with something like:

```
#bgmask{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    position: absolute;
    right:10%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:999;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**HERE IS A JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/xLx68/1/**

Comment: can you please  elaborate this .

Answer (score 1):

You put `cursor: pointer` in your CSS class `post1_img` and then you put `cursor: <something else>` in the style/CSS of everything that's inside it.

Example, if your DIV contains just a form (so everything is an `input` element of different `type`):

```
#post1_img {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:280px;
    height:33px;
    background:url(../images/assets/pullTab-readMore-off-.png) no-repeat top center;
    clear:both;
}

#post1_img input {
     cursor: auto; /*just an example*/
}
```

As for giving a class name for the background, it's not possible because the background is not an HTML element per-se.

EDIT: Fixed the `cursor` in the second css block

Comment: Odd, it works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/gDyp9/2/ (run and move the mouse over the gray area and the textboxes). Note that it *only* takes care of the mouse cursor issue.